# Java Quicksort quadratic runtime behaviour

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, quicksort

I tried to implement an efficient sorting algorithm in Java. For this reason, I also implemented quicksort and use the following code:

```
public class Sorting {
    private static Random prng;

    private static Random getPrng() {
        if (prng == null) {
            prng = new Random();
        }
        return prng;
    }

    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sortInternal(array, 0, array.length - 1);
    }

    public static void sortInternal(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        if (end - start < 50) {
            insertionSortInternal(array, start, end);
        } else {
            quickSortInternal(array, start, end);
        }
    }

    private static void insertionSortInternal(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        for (int i=start; i<end - 1; ++i) {
            for (int ptr=i; ptr>0 && array[ptr - 1] < array[ptr]; ptr--) {
                ArrayUtilities.swap(array, ptr, ptr - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void quickSortInternal(int[] array, int start, int end) {
        int pivotPos = getPrng().nextInt(end - start);
        int pivot = array[start + pivotPos];
        ArrayUtilities.swap(array, start + pivotPos, end - 1);
        int left = start;
        int right = end - 2;
        while (left < right) {
            while (array[left] <= pivot && left < right) {
                ++left;
            }
            if (left == right) break;
            while (array[right] >= pivot && left < right) {
                right--;
            }
            if (left == right) break;
            ArrayUtilities.swap(array, left, right);
        }
        ArrayUtilities.swap(array, left, end - 1);
        sortInternal(array, start, left);
        sortInternal(array, left + 1, end);
    }
}
```

`ArrayUtilities.swap` just swaps the two given elements in the array. From this code, I expect `O(n log(n))` runtime behaviour. But, some different lengths of arrays to sort gave the following results:

10000 elements: 32ms

20000 elements: 128ms

30000 elements: 296ms

The test ran 100 times in each case, and then the arithmetic mean of the running times was calculated. But clearly, as opposed to the expected behaviour, the runtime is `O(n^2)`. What's wrong with my algorithm?

Comment: Quicksort of course has `O(n lg n)` **best case** performance, but is also has [`O(n^2)`  **worst case** performance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). Why do you expect best case performance in your benchmarks? (assuming of course you have benchmarked with JMH, and not by hand, in which case the numbers are likely meaningless anyway)

Comment: for inspiration http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/ and http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/23Quicksort.pdf and https://github.com/edermag/algorithms.princeton/blob/master/java/QuickSort.java

Comment: How are you populating your input array? It looks like your quicksort doesn't have any intelligent handling for duplicates, so if the input has a lot of duplicate elements, the performance will degrade to O(n^2).

Comment: @blazs  sorry; but what are you trying to tell me?

Comment: Ops sorry. I wanted to make sure that the OP repeated the time measurements 100 times on the same array of given length. (Since the running time analysis is independent of the input, this shouldn't matter, but let's see how the experiment was done. Maybe that can hint us where the problem lies.)

Comment: @BoristheSpider the running time of this algorithm should be O(n log n) with high probability---you can prove that the probability of the algorithm taking more than 24*n log n operations is less than 1/1000 under some reasonable assumptions---, so something really weird goes on here. I suspect the arrays may have many duplicates.

Comment: @blazs The arrays are populated by selecting each element as a random number between 0 and (upper bound)^2. The arrays were different on each run to prevent particularities of a certain array that makes sorting it last longer than the average case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insertion-sort implementation your array will be sorted in descending order, while in your quick-sort the array is sorted in ascending order. So replace(for descending order):

```
for (int ptr=i; ptr>0 && array[ptr - 1] < array[ptr]; ptr--)
```

with

```
for (int ptr=i; ptr>0 && array[ptr - 1] > array[ptr]; ptr--)
```

It also seems like your indexing is not correct.
Try to replace:

```
sortInternal(array, 0, array.length - 1);
```

with:

```
sortInternal(array, 0, array.length);
```

And in the insertions sort first for loop you don't need to do `end - 1`, i.e. use:

```
for (int i=start; i<end; ++i)
```

Finally, add `if (start >= end) return;` at the beginning of the quick-sort method.

And as @ljeabmreosn mentioned, 50 is a little bit too large, I would have chosen something between 5 and 20.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nearly everything is correct here. Insertion sort sorted in descending order, and `for (int ptr=i; ptr>0 && array[ptr - 1] < array[ptr]; ptr--)` needs to be replaced by `for (int ptr=i; ptr>start && array[ptr-1] > array[ptr]; ptr--)` (in fact, the wrong version sorts the array descending by insertion sort, which has quadratic runtime). The indexing problems were also present. `if (start >= end) return;` is unneccessary because quicksort is not used for that small arrays. Finally, I replaced the 50 by 30 which is the optimal choice in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The QuickSort "optimized" with Insertion Sort for arrays with length less than 50 elements seems to be a problem.

Imagine I had an array of size 65, and the pivot happened to be the median of that array. If I ran the array through your code, your code would use Insertion Sort on the two 32 length subarrays to the left and right of the pivot. This would result in ~O(2*(n/2)^2 + n) = ~O(n^2) average case. Using quick sort and implementing [a pivot picking strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) for the first pivot, the time average case would be ~O((n*log(n)) + n) = ~O(n*(log(n) + 1)) = ~O(n*log(n)). Don't use Insertion Sort as it is only used when the array is almost sorted. If you are using Insertion Sort solely because of the real running time of sorting small arrays might run faster than the standard quick sort algorithm (deep recursion), you can always utilize a non-recursive quick sort algorithm which runs faster than Insertion Sort.

Maybe change the "50" to "20" and observe the results.

Comment: As I cannot comment on posts yet (my rep < 50), hanif's solution is incorrect: "array.length - 1" is needed because of Java's (and nearly every other programming language's) zero-based indices. However, using "i < end" instead of "i < end - 1" is needed since end is one less than the length of the array. But, the idea is there: the last iteration does not need to be done in Insertion Sort as the last element should already be in place.

Comment: The insertion sort optimization is not the problem: As the bound 50 is fixed, the runtime behaviour should not be quadratic. Insertion sort is just faster for smaller arrays than quicksort, and larger ones are sorted with the average case `O(n log(n))` quicksort.

Comment: Additionally, the quadratic runtime behaviour in the given case is incorrect: Sorting an array with size 65 has O(1) runtime. Insertion sort is just faster for smaller arrays because it has less overhead than quicksort (pivot picking, partitioning etc.).